# Select min, max and one row that has a special FK

Tags: oracle, select, oracle-apex

sorry I couldn't think of a better title.

I have a table like this:

```
...
DATE (datetime)
PROJECT (number - this is a FK to projects table)
FROM (datetime)
TO (datetime)
...
```

And I need to select the lowest FROM value for each day (as a time the work day started), biggest TO value (as s time the work day ended) and a FROM and TO for a project marked as a "BREAK", so the output will look like this:

```
date     from to     break from break to time spent 
1.1.2011 9:00 17:00 12:00       13:00    7.0
```

Is this somehow possible to do in one select? So far I have this:

```
SELECT 
  MIN("FROM_X") AS "FROM",
  MAX("TO_X") AS "TO",
  (MAX("TO_X") - MIN("FROM_X"))*24 AS TIME_SPENT,
  "DAY"
FROM ATTENDANCE_HOURS
GROUP BY DAY
```

It takes care of the start and the end of the work day, but I have no idea how to include the break thing.

Comment: What is the PK and possibly UK for your attendance_hours table? is the column called date (that'd be a bad choice) or day? Why is the grouping on day required/why are there multiple records per day in attendance_hours - are they per project? I don't exactly get how the projects come into this?

Comment: PK is a number "ID". I didn't mention it b/c it didn't seem relevant. Yep, the column is named DAY. Well, it represents hours spent by employees on projects - so yep, each record stands for X hours spent on one project in one day. From that, I need to extract when person started and left work on each day and also, when did he have break (represented also as a project).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If "break" project appears only once every day, you can use:

```
SELECT 
  MIN("FROM_X") AS "FROM",
  MAX("TO_X") AS "TO",
  max(case when project = 'break' then from_x else null end) as "BREAK FROM",
  max(case when project = 'break' then to_x else null end) as "BREAK TO",
  (MAX("TO_X") - MIN("FROM_X"))*24 AS TIME_SPENT,
  "DAY"
FROM ATTENDANCE_HOURS
GROUP BY DAY
```

If not, you need to choose appropriate aggregate function. Also you can use this solution to exclude your "break" project from first two columns:

```
SELECT 
  max(case when project <> 'break' then from_x else null end) as "FROM",
  max(case when project <> 'break' then to_x else null end) as "TO",
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed AND saved my day, can I offer you my firstborn?